# How can I click element which matches the text

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, capybara-webkit

```
<div class="list-title-name ng-binding"> NEW LIST </div>
<div class="list-title-name ng-binding"> Things I Like </div>
```

I want to click the element which matches the text NEW LIST

```
find("div.list-title-name" == NEW LIST).click #wrong method but want something like this
```

Can anyone specify a valid capybara method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want

```
find('div.list-title-name', text: 'NEW LIST').click()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am a newbie for Capybara & your answer solved many of my issues

`<a class="btn ng-scope" translate="" href="/lists/NEW LIST/46190285">See All</a>`

Could you please tell me how can I click the button with href?

I tried this:

    `find("a.btn", href: "/lists/NEW LIST/46190285").click`


Also, the href value will be different for each user so I want to use REGEX of href instead of using the whole href value

Comment: As documented - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders%3Afind `#find` doesn't have an href option - you can do what you're trying to do with a css selector  `find("a.btn[href='/lists/NEW LIST/46190285']")` which won't let you do regex but will let you do starts_with, ends_with, etc using the correct css selectors  ^=, $=, etc.  The other option is `find_link` which supports an href option `find_link('See All', href: "/lists/NEW LIST/46190285")` where you can use a regex or string. Note: clicking links based on href makes for brittle tests if you ever change your routes

Comment: Thanks @Tom ...

    `find("a.btn[href^='/lists/NEW LIST/']").click` worked perfectly

Comment: `<a class="bottom-action-container quickview-button hover-option" track="{ type: 'product-info', name: moduleType, breadcrumbs: result.breadcrumbs || breadcrumbs }" ng-click="ProductUtils.cache(result)" title="Christian Dior So Real" Sunglasses-Colorless" href="/g/women/christian-dior/so-real-sunglasses-colorless">`

I want to get the href & title to store them into text

Comment: after you've found the element - element[:href] and element[:title] will give you what you want -- ask further things as new questions since putting question in comments doesnt help the rest of the community